# docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock' - Windows 10

Tags: docker-daemon, appwrite

I want to install Appwrite for Windows 10, I copied and pasted the CMD command in their installation docs but I keep getting:

> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification:
> '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'

PS: I have docker installed.

---

I tried to run the CMD as a administrator and tried to use download it from PowerShell, but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have WSL 2 installed and Docker is configured to use WSL 2 based engine.

Additional references:

1. Docker docs on WSL: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/
2. GitHub Issue: https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/issues/5026#issuecomment-1408162967